# Async Node/Mongoose problems when loading data from csv file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I'm new to Node and asynchronous programming in general and I just can't wrap my head around this problem.

I'm importing data on registered voters into MongoDB using Mongoose. As you can imagine, many voters live on the same street. During my import, I check to see if a street already exists. If it does not, I need to create a new Street document. If it does, I simply want to create an Address subdocument.

The problem I'm having is I don't know how to handle the fact that the find() Mongoose commands are asynchronous. So what happens in my code is that as the CSV rows are parsed, all the find commands are queued but not executed immediately. My program reads one row, sees a record for "Choctaw St" for example, and queues up a find() command to see if it exists. But the very next row could also be Choctaw St and another find() command will be queued. The creation of the document in Mongo happens in the callback of the find() command which may not run until after all the find commands are executed. So as the finds are ran one after the other, the program will attempt to create the document multiple times

Here is a snippet from my code:

```
Street.findOne(
{
    campaign_id: user_id,
    street_name: streetData.street_name,
    city: streetData.city
},
function(err, foundStreet) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }

    if(foundStreet) {
        console.log('Found street: ' + foundStreet.street_name + '. Not adding!!!')
        //Code for address insertion will go here.
    } else {
        console.log(streetData.street_name + ' not found. Adding now.')
        let newStreet = new Street({
            campaign_id: user_id,
            street_name: streetData.street_name,
            city: streetData.city
        })

        newStreet.save((err, streetDoc) => {
            if(err) { 
                console.log('Error creating street: ' + newStreet.street_name)
            }

            if(streetDoc) {
                console.log('Street created: ' + streetDoc.street_name)
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Below is the output of my program that highlights my problem. I apologize in advance for the length. As you can see, the errors are thrown when an attempt is made to create duplicate street documents.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can't believe my case is that special, but I've been stuck on this problem for 3 days and have yet to find a solution.

```
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"DEERPATH RD","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"HUNTINGTON PL","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"SULLIVAN DR","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"QUAIL CREEK DR","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"N CHEROKEE AVE","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"STEEPLECHASE CT","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"LOCKWYNN TRCE","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"SHOREWOOD DR","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"TWIN OAKS LN","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"BAKER TRCE","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"N ENGLEWOOD AVE","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"PLANTATION RD","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"OVERLOOK DR","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"ADRIAN RD","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"DEERPATH RD","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"N CHEROKEE AVE","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"EMERALD LAKE DR","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"RADCLIFF RD","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"BAKER TRCE","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"GABRIEL CT","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"RENDALE RD","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"MILL RIDGE RD","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"CHOCTAW ST","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"RICHMOND RD","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"BRIARCLIFF RD","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"GIRARD AVE","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"HEATHERBROOK PL","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"CARDINAL CT","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"GARDENIA DR","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"HOUSTON ST","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"BUENA VISTA DR","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"MOCKINGBIRD LN","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"LASALLE DR","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"WHIFFLETREE WAY","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"LOBLOLLY LN","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"DEERPATH RD","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"FOXRIDGE RD","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"AZURE DR","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"SHADYBROOK LN","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"FAIRFIELD DR","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"AZURE DR","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"QUAIL CREEK DR","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"SUMMERRAIN TER","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"FAIRFIELD DR","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
DEERPATH RD not found. Adding now.
STEEPLECHASE CT not found. Adding now.
QUAIL CREEK DR not found. Adding now.
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"HUNTINGTON PL","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
N CHEROKEE AVE not found. Adding now.
Street created: DEERPATH RD
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"N PONTIAC AVE","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"N CHEROKEE AVE","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"IMPALA DR","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"BAKER TRCE","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"AZURE DR","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Street created: STEEPLECHASE CT
BAKER TRCE not found. Adding now.
DEERPATH RD not found. Adding now.
GABRIEL CT not found. Adding now.
BRIARCLIFF RD not found. Adding now.
HOUSTON ST not found. Adding now.
LOBLOLLY LN not found. Adding now.
FAIRFIELD DR not found. Adding now.
TWIN OAKS LN not found. Adding now.
ADRIAN RD not found. Adding now.
BAKER TRCE not found. Adding now.
RICHMOND RD not found. Adding now.
GARDENIA DR not found. Adding now.
WHIFFLETREE WAY not found. Adding now.
SHADYBROOK LN not found. Adding now.
FAIRFIELD DR not found. Adding now.
SULLIVAN DR not found. Adding now.
SHOREWOOD DR not found. Adding now.
OVERLOOK DR not found. Adding now.
RADCLIFF RD not found. Adding now.
N ENGLEWOOD AVE not found. Adding now.
N CHEROKEE AVE not found. Adding now.
RENDALE RD not found. Adding now.
GIRARD AVE not found. Adding now.
BUENA VISTA DR not found. Adding now.
DEERPATH RD not found. Adding now.
AZURE DR not found. Adding now.
Street created: N CHEROKEE AVE
Adding streetData: {"campaign_id":"59dcde03ea6bdc44cb51b655","street_name":"HAYES DR","city":"DOTHAN","addresses":[]}
Street created: QUAIL CREEK DR
N PONTIAC AVE not found. Adding now.
AZURE DR not found. Adding now.
CHOCTAW ST not found. Adding now.
CARDINAL CT not found. Adding now.
LASALLE DR not found. Adding now.
AZURE DR not found. Adding now.
SUMMERRAIN TER not found. Adding now.
HUNTINGTON PL not found. Adding now.
BAKER TRCE not found. Adding now.
Found street: N CHEROKEE AVE. Not adding!!!
HUNTINGTON PL not found. Adding now.
LOCKWYNN TRCE not found. Adding now.
PLANTATION RD not found. Adding now.
EMERALD LAKE DR not found. Adding now.
MILL RIDGE RD not found. Adding now.
HEATHERBROOK PL not found. Adding now.
MOCKINGBIRD LN not found. Adding now.
FOXRIDGE RD not found. Adding now.
QUAIL CREEK DR not found. Adding now.
IMPALA DR not found. Adding now.
Street created: HOUSTON ST
Street created: BAKER TRCE
Street created: FAIRFIELD DR
Street created: N ENGLEWOOD AVE
Error creating street: DEERPATH RD
Street created: GARDENIA DR
Street created: SHOREWOOD DR
Street created: RENDALE RD
Error creating street: DEERPATH RD
Error creating street: FAIRFIELD DR
Street created: BRIARCLIFF RD
Street created: ADRIAN RD
Street created: SHADYBROOK LN
Street created: RADCLIFF RD
Street created: BUENA VISTA DR
Street created: GABRIEL CT
Street created: TWIN OAKS LN
Street created: WHIFFLETREE WAY
Street created: OVERLOOK DR
Street created: GIRARD AVE
Street created: LOBLOLLY LN
Street created: RICHMOND RD
Street created: SULLIVAN DR
Street created: AZURE DR
Error creating street: BAKER TRCE
Error creating street: N CHEROKEE AVE
HAYES DR not found. Adding now.
Street created: CHOCTAW ST
Error creating street: AZURE DR
Street created: N PONTIAC AVE
Street created: HUNTINGTON PL
Error creating street: AZURE DR
Street created: CARDINAL CT
Street created: MILL RIDGE RD
Error creating street: BAKER TRCE
Street created: LASALLE DR
Street created: EMERALD LAKE DR
Error creating street: QUAIL CREEK DR
Street created: IMPALA DR
Street created: SUMMERRAIN TER
Street created: PLANTATION RD
Street created: LOCKWYNN TRCE
Street created: MOCKINGBIRD LN
Street created: FOXRIDGE RD
Street created: HEATHERBROOK PL
Error creating street: HUNTINGTON PL
Street created: HAYES DR
```